# Merge the content of selected files in a .txt, then rename the txt e move it in another folder

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have the following problem that I'm trying to solve with batch scripting.
I have a folder that contains multiple .txt files. Some of these files, have to be merged into a file called "parmalat90" (without extension) then moved to a directory.
The .bat file should work in the same folder where it is placed. The .txt files that it has to merge and then move to the other folder, must be which has been selected by the user through windows explorer. Here is what I was able to write down. Please help me to complete this task, I open also to change environment if needed (maybe PowerShell?). Thank you very much for your time and knowledge.

```
for %f in (*.txt) do type "%f" >> parmalat90
move parmalat90 \\192.168.1.251\filetra\parmalat
```

EDIT: Thanks to Magoo my first problem is solved (check his comment down below). Now my code is

```
for %%f in (*.txt) do type "%%f" >> parmalat90 
move parmalat90 \\192.168.1.251\filetra\parmalat
```

how can use it only on selected files instead of all the .txt inside the folder?

EDIT 2: Thanks too Aacini I solved the second problem. The syntax was the following

```
type %* >> parmalat90 2>nul
```

Comment: What's the issue with the code above? PowerShell tag removed: if you'd like help with how to do it in PowerShell, give it a go, post code and tell us the *specific* problem.

Comment: If you read the help file, it says this as the first description after the syntax usage: `To use the FOR command in a batch program, specify %%variable instead of %variable.  Variable names are case sensitive, so %i is different from %I.`

Comment: Try: `type %* >> parmalat90 2>nul` This should work when the selected files are pasted into the Batch file.

Comment: Thank you for the info Squashman, I will do a better use of the help file next time.

Comment: Thank you Aacini, you made me cry of joy

Comment: Cry = not worked? of joy = worked?  **`:/`**  May I ask you to accept this as Best answer if I post it? Please, include @Aacini in your comment,,,

Comment: @Aacini this worked and I'm using this script at my job place. Thank you. Actually i'm using this 'for %%f in (*.txt) do type "%%f" >> parmalat90 
move parmalat90 \\192.168.1.251\filetra\parmalat'  and I'm trying to improve it. Since every time I use the script the file parmalat90 in \\192.168.1.251\filetra\parmalat is replaced, I would know how to append the content instead of replacing it

Comment: Please, select the check mark of my answer below. Doing that will mark this question as "answered" and give rep points to both you and me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
type %* >> parmalat90 2>nul
```

The `type` command may show several files given in the parameters, so `type %*` will process all files that have been selected via the explorer and dropped into the Batch file.

However, in this case the `type` command also includes the names of the files (that are output via stderr handle #2), so it is necessary to add `2>nul` to omit the name of the files.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! Acually i'm using this single row `type %* >> \\192.168.1.251\filetra\parmalat\parmalat90 2>nul` that update the file in the path for every paste

Comment: So? I asked you: _"May I ask you to accept this as Best answer if I post it?"_ and your reply was: _"@Aacini this worked and I'm using this script at my job place"_ that I understood as a **Yes**! Why did you accepted the other answer? **`:(`**

Comment: @GiuseppeCav: So?

Comment: how can i choose the best answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
for %f in (*.txt) do type "%f" >> parmalat90
```

Within a batch file, you need to double the `%` for metavariables.

```
for %%f in (*.txt) do type "%%f" >> parmalat90
```

Comment: this is my code now for %%f in (*.txt) do type "%%f" >> parmalat90
move parmalat90 \\192.168.1.251\filetra\parmalat how can use it only on selected files instead of all the .txt?